# Reduce an array by ID and by item in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, mapreduce, reduce

I have an arrangement that I need to take an average of a sum based on the user who attended an activity

I have an array where there is a list of activities, so suppose that the activity of the day "2022-11-25", which was a Friday, was attended by the entire organization, so the status `isAttendanceAllOrg` is true for Therefore, the `usersNotAttendance` array is empty, but on "2022-11-26" which was a Saturday, the entire organization did not attend, therefore the `isAttendanceAllOrg` status would go to false and in `usersNotAttendance` we would bring the users who did not attend the activity. Now we need to assign the minimum hours for each day, respectively.

But to do so we must take into account which modality the user belongs to. If the user is Fulltime, we use `minTracked`, but if it is part time, we will use `minTrackedPartime`. That is, the day "2022-11-25", which was a Friday. It was established that the minimum number of hours in Fulltime was **"minTracked: 6"** and the half-time ones were **"minTrackedPartime: 2.5"** and on Saturday a **"minTracked: 3"** for Fulltime and for Parttime a **"minTrackedPartime: 3"**, so we need to find a way to average out `minTracked` and `minTrackedPartime` based on users who attended or not.

For example, as the day "2022-11-25" the user with the ID "1267" which is part time attended the activity, but the day "2022-11-26" did not, then his final average would be **"totalTracked: 2.5"**, since the **"minTrackedPartime"** of the day "2022-11-26" is not being added because he did not attend. Quite the contrary, for that user, who did attend both activities on both days and that is full time, his average final would be the minTracked of date 25 plus the minTracked of date 26 which would be equal to 6 + 3 = 9.

So I have to be able to get a list of all the users with pertinent information on the modalities and their ID:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1278,
        "name": "User18",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 30,
            "tittle": "DEV",
            "priority": 0,
            "type": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:08+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 4,
            "job_position": "Trainee Fulltime",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:54:17.963682+00:00",
            "status": true
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1273,
        "username": "User17",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 31,
            "tittle": "SAC",
            "priority": 1,
            "type": 2,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:33+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 4,
            "job_position": "Trainee Fulltime",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:54:17.963682+00:00",
            "status": true
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1288,
        "username": "User16",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 30,
            "tittle": "DEV",
            "priority": 0,
            "type": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:08+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 4,
            "job_position": "Trainee Fulltime",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:54:17.963682+00:00",
            "status": true
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1279,
        "username": "User15",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 30,
            "tittle": "DEV",
            "priority": 0,
            "type": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:08+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 4,
            "job_position": "Trainee Fulltime",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:54:17.963682+00:00",
            "status": true
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1287,
        "username": "User14",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 30,
            "tittle": "DEV",
            "priority": 0,
            "type": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:08+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 4,
            "job_position": "Trainee Fulltime",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:54:17.963682+00:00",
            "status": true
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1277,
        "username": "User13",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 30,
            "tittle": "DEV",
            "priority": 0,
            "type": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:08+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 4,
            "job_position": "Trainee Fulltime",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:54:17.963682+00:00",
            "status": true
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1270,
        "username": "User12",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 30,
            "tittle": "DEV",
            "priority": 0,
            "type": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:08+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 2,
            "job_position": "Junior",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:53:41.024661+00:00",
            "status": false
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1272,
        "username": "User11",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 31,
            "tittle": "SAC",
            "priority": 1,
            "type": 2,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:33+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 4,
            "job_position": "Trainee Fulltime",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:54:17.963682+00:00",
            "status": true
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1282,
        "name": "User10",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 30,
            "tittle": "DEV",
            "priority": 0,
            "type": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:08+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 4,
            "job_position": "Trainee Fulltime",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:54:17.963682+00:00",
            "status": true
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1266,
        "username": "User09",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 30,
            "tittle": "DEV",
            "priority": 0,
            "type": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:08+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 5,
            "job_position": "Senior",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:54:33.127234+00:00",
            "status": true
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1276,
        "username": "User08",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 30,
            "tittle": "DEV",
            "priority": 0,
            "type": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:08+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 2,
            "job_position": "Junior",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:53:41.024661+00:00",
            "status": false
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1264,
        "username": "User08",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 30,
            "tittle": "DEV",
            "priority": 0,
            "type": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:08+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 5,
            "job_position": "Senior",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:54:33.127234+00:00",
            "status": true
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1281,
        "username": "User07",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 31,
            "tittle": "SAC",
            "priority": 1,
            "type": 2,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:33+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 4,
            "job_position": "Trainee Fulltime",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:54:17.963682+00:00",
            "status": true
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1268,
        "username": "User06",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 30,
            "tittle": "DEV",
            "priority": 0,
            "type": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:08+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 2,
            "job_position": "Junior",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:53:41.024661+00:00",
            "status": false
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1269,
        "username": "User05",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 30,
            "tittle": "DEV",
            "priority": 0,
            "type": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:08+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 2,
            "job_position": "Junior",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:53:41.024661+00:00",
            "status": false
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1265,
        "username": "User04",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 30,
            "tittle": "DEV",
            "priority": 0,
            "type": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:08+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 5,
            "job_position": "Senior",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:54:33.127234+00:00",
            "status": true
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1292,
        "username": "User03",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 32,
            "tittle": "DESIGN",
            "priority": 2,
            "type": 3,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:51+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 4,
            "job_position": "Trainee Fulltime",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:54:17.963682+00:00",
            "status": true
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1274,
        "username": "User02",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 30,
            "tittle": "DEV",
            "priority": 0,
            "type": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:08+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 2,
            "job_position": "Junior",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:53:41.024661+00:00",
            "status": false
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1267,
        "username": "User01",
        "modality": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "PARTTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 24,
            "daily_hours": 4,
            "monthly_hours": 104,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:47:13.961156+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 30,
            "tittle": "DEV",
            "priority": 0,
            "type": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:08+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 5,
            "job_position": "Senior",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:54:33.127234+00:00",
            "status": true
        }
    }
]
```

And a list of activities

```
[
    {
        "id": 18,
        "created_at": "2022-11-30T22:07:29.47307+00:00",
        "date_start": "2022-11-25",
        "date_end": "2022-11-25",
        "indicator_hours": 3,
        "id_org": 1,
        "minTracked": 6,
        "minActivity": 20,
        "isAttendanceAllOrg": true,
        "usersNotAttendance": [],
        "description": "ACTIVIDAD DE PRUEBA",
        "type_of_schedule": "activity",
        "indicator_activity": 2,
        "minTrackedPartime": 2.5,
        "minActivityPartime": 10
    },
    {
        "id": 20,
        "created_at": "2022-11-30T22:41:16.081726+00:00",
        "date_start": "2022-11-26",
        "date_end": "2022-11-26",
        "indicator_hours": 3,
        "id_org": 1,
        "minTracked": 3,
        "minActivity": 10,
        "isAttendanceAllOrg": false,
        "usersNotAttendance": [
            {
                "isWork": true,
                "id_user": 1267
            },
            {
                "isWork": true,
                "id_user": 1274
            },
            {
                "isWork": true,
                "id_user": 1292
            }
        ],
        "description": "ACTIVIDAD SIN ASISTENTES",
        "type_of_schedule": "activity",
        "indicator_activity": 3,
        "minTrackedPartime": 3,
        "minActivityPartime": 20
    }
]
```

And my output should be something like:

```
[{
   "user_id": 1267,
   "username": "User01",
   "modality": "PARTTIME",
   "totalTracked": 2.5
},
{
   "user_id": 1274,
   "username": "User02",
   "modality": "FULLTIME",
   "totalTracked": 6
},
{
   "user_id": 1292,
   "username": "User03",
"modality": "FULLTIME",
   "totalTracked": 6
},
{
   "user_id": 1268,
   "username": "User06",
"modality": "FULLTIME",
   "totalTracked": 9
},
{
   "user_id": 1264,
   "username": "User08",
"modality": "FULLTIME",
   "totalTracked": 9
},
{
   "user_id": 1277,
   "username": "User13",
"modality": "FULLTIME",
   "totalTracked": 9
}
.
.
.
{
   "user_id": 1278,
   "username": "User18",
"modality": "FULLTIME",
   "totalTracked": 9
}]
```

I was thinking that maybe with a reduce in the array, where we are filtering by the user ID like they did in this example [Reduce array of objects by user_id and sum certain values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53826570/reduce-array-of-objects-by-user%20-id-and-sum-certain-values), but since the id that I am accessing is inside `usersNotAttendance` it is difficult for me to understand how to filter it in such a way that it can be accessed.

Comment: "M" in [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is for "minimal".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find the solution to my problem. In the end I was applying the logic wrong.

Since in reality I had to manage to list the users who did attend the schedule because they are the ones who are affected with a minimum of hours while those who do not attend are not taken into account, so adding the final average does not affect in my results.

So thinking about it, I did change the list. Now it is `listusersAttendance` and here I list all those who go to the schedule. I also handle a status for in the event that everyone attends yes or yes always handling the status `isAttendanceAllOrg`.

Because in reality it is what I really need; I need to know who attends, identify who, when they attended and when the 'minTracked' according to their modality.

With that modified, I iterated the array as @EugenSunic was kind enough to explain to me. It is only a forEach, so that for each element of the array the users that come within the schedule are being validated, and then I add some more validations that have to do with my use cases. But in itself, the question was how could iterate the arrangement and it was achieved.

Thank you very much!

**DEMO**

```js
 const attendance_schedule = [
        {
            "id": 20,
            "created_at": "2022-11-30T22:41:16.081726+00:00",
            "date_start": "2022-11-26",
            "date_end": "2022-11-26",
            "indicator_hours": 3,
            "id_org": 1,
            "minTracked": 0,
            "minActivity": 0,
            "isAttendanceAllOrg": false,
            "listusersAttendance": [
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1274
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1292
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1265
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1269
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1268
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1281
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1264
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1276
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1266
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1282
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1272
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1270
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1277
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1289
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1279
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1288
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1273
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1278
                }
            ],
            "description": "ACTIVIDAD SIN ASISTENTES",
            "type_of_schedule": "activity",
            "indicator_activity": 3,
            "minTrackedPartime": 0,
            "minActivityPartime": 0,
            "minTrackedPartimeW": 3,
            "minTrackedFulltimeW": 3,
            "minActivityPartimeW": 50,
            "minActivityFulltimeW": 50
        },
        {
            "id": 18,
            "created_at": "2022-11-30T22:07:29.47307+00:00",
            "date_start": "2022-11-25",
            "date_end": "2022-11-25",
            "indicator_hours": 3,
            "id_org": 1,
            "minTracked": 6,
            "minActivity": 20,
            "isAttendanceAllOrg": false,
            "listusersAttendance":[
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1274
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1292
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1265
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1269
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1268
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1281
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1264
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1276
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1266
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1282
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1272
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1270
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1277
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1289
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1279
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1288
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1273
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1278
                },
                {
                    "isWork": true,
                    "id_user": 1267
                }
            ],
            "description": "ACTIVIDAD DE PRUEBA",
            "type_of_schedule": "activity",
            "indicator_activity": 2,
            "minTrackedPartime": 2.5,
            "minActivityPartime": 10,
            "minTrackedPartimeW": null,
            "minTrackedFulltimeW": null,
            "minActivityPartimeW": null,
            "minActivityFulltimeW": null
        }
    ]


    const users = [
    {
        "id": 1278,
        "username": "User18",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 30,
            "tittle": "DEV",
            "priority": 0,
            "type": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:08+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 4,
            "job_position": "Trainee Fulltime",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:54:17.963682+00:00",
            "status": true
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1273,
        "username": "User17",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 31,
            "tittle": "SAC",
            "priority": 1,
            "type": 2,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:33+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 4,
            "job_position": "Trainee Fulltime",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:54:17.963682+00:00",
            "status": true
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1288,
        "username": "User16",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 30,
            "tittle": "DEV",
            "priority": 0,
            "type": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:08+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 4,
            "job_position": "Trainee Fulltime",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:54:17.963682+00:00",
            "status": true
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1279,
        "username": "User15",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 30,
            "tittle": "DEV",
            "priority": 0,
            "type": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:08+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 4,
            "job_position": "Trainee Fulltime",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:54:17.963682+00:00",
            "status": true
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1287,
        "username": "User14",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 30,
            "tittle": "DEV",
            "priority": 0,
            "type": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:08+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 4,
            "job_position": "Trainee Fulltime",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:54:17.963682+00:00",
            "status": true
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1277,
        "username": "User13",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 30,
            "tittle": "DEV",
            "priority": 0,
            "type": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:08+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 4,
            "job_position": "Trainee Fulltime",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:54:17.963682+00:00",
            "status": true
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1270,
        "username": "User12",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 30,
            "tittle": "DEV",
            "priority": 0,
            "type": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:08+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 2,
            "job_position": "Junior",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:53:41.024661+00:00",
            "status": false
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1272,
        "username": "User11",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 31,
            "tittle": "SAC",
            "priority": 1,
            "type": 2,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:33+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 4,
            "job_position": "Trainee Fulltime",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:54:17.963682+00:00",
            "status": true
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1282,
        "name": "User10",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 30,
            "tittle": "DEV",
            "priority": 0,
            "type": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:08+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 4,
            "job_position": "Trainee Fulltime",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:54:17.963682+00:00",
            "status": true
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1266,
        "username": "User09",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 30,
            "tittle": "DEV",
            "priority": 0,
            "type": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:08+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 5,
            "job_position": "Senior",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:54:33.127234+00:00",
            "status": true
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1276,
        "username": "User08",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 30,
            "tittle": "DEV",
            "priority": 0,
            "type": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:08+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 2,
            "job_position": "Junior",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:53:41.024661+00:00",
            "status": false
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1264,
        "username": "User08",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 30,
            "tittle": "DEV",
            "priority": 0,
            "type": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:08+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 5,
            "job_position": "Senior",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:54:33.127234+00:00",
            "status": true
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1281,
        "username": "User07",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 31,
            "tittle": "SAC",
            "priority": 1,
            "type": 2,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:33+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 4,
            "job_position": "Trainee Fulltime",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:54:17.963682+00:00",
            "status": true
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1268,
        "username": "User06",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 30,
            "tittle": "DEV",
            "priority": 0,
            "type": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:08+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 2,
            "job_position": "Junior",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:53:41.024661+00:00",
            "status": false
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1269,
        "username": "User05",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 30,
            "tittle": "DEV",
            "priority": 0,
            "type": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:08+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 2,
            "job_position": "Junior",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:53:41.024661+00:00",
            "status": false
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1265,
        "username": "User04",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 30,
            "tittle": "DEV",
            "priority": 0,
            "type": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:08+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 5,
            "job_position": "Senior",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:54:33.127234+00:00",
            "status": true
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1292,
        "username": "User03",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 32,
            "tittle": "DESIGN",
            "priority": 2,
            "type": 3,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:51+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 4,
            "job_position": "Trainee Fulltime",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:54:17.963682+00:00",
            "status": true
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1274,
        "username": "User02",
        "modality": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FULLTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 44,
            "daily_hours": 8,
            "monthly_hours": 192,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:46:07.169271+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 30,
            "tittle": "DEV",
            "priority": 0,
            "type": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:08+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 2,
            "job_position": "Junior",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:53:41.024661+00:00",
            "status": false
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1267,
        "username": "User01",
        "modality": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "PARTTIME",
            "weekly_hours": 24,
            "daily_hours": 4,
            "monthly_hours": 104,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T20:47:13.961156+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "rol": {
            "id": 30,
            "tittle": "DEV",
            "priority": 0,
            "type": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:05:08+00:00",
            "status": true
        },
        "job_position": {
            "id": 5,
            "job_position": "Senior",
            "created_at": "2022-11-02T21:54:33.127234+00:00",
            "status": true
        }
    }
];
    let isActivity = [];
    let isHoliday= [];
    let isWorkingDays = [];
    let newArrayOfAttendanceInWorkingDays = [];
    let isWeekendsDays = [];
    let newArrayOfAttendanceInWeekendDays = [];
    let newListOfSchedule= [];

 users.map(user => {

                let user_id = user.id;
                let username = user.username;
                let modality = user.modality.name;
                let totalTracked= 0;
                let newDailyHours = 0;

                attendance_schedule.forEach(schedule => {

                    const dateMomentForSchedule = moment(schedule.date_start);
                    const dailyHoursInFulltime = 8;
                    const dailyHoursInParttime = 4;
                    const dailyHoursInFulltimeInWeekend = 4;
                    const dailyHoursInParttimeInWeekend = 4;

                    // Check if the user is part of the schedule
                    if ((schedule.isAttendanceAllOrg === false && schedule.listusersAttendance.some(u => u.id_user === user.id))) {
                        // The user is part of the schedule, so determine the value of totalTracked
                        // revisar las modalidad para asignar el nuevo daily hours que depende de la calendarizacion
                        if (modality === "FULLTIME") {
                            totalTracked = (dateMomentForSchedule.day() === 0 || dateMomentForSchedule.day() === 6) ? schedule.minTrackedFulltimeW : schedule.minTracked;                            newDailyHours = (dateMomentForSchedule.day() === 0 || dateMomentForSchedule.day() === 6) ? (dailyHoursInFulltimeInWeekend - totalTracked) : (dailyHoursInFulltime - totalTracked) ?? 0;
                        } else if (modality === "PARTTIME") {
                            totalTracked = (dateMomentForSchedule.day() === 0 || dateMomentForSchedule.day() === 6) ? schedule.minTrackedPartimeW : schedule.minTrackedPartime;
                            newDailyHours = (dateMomentForSchedule.day() === 0 || dateMomentForSchedule.day() === 6) ? (dailyHoursInParttimeInWeekend - totalTracked) : (dailyHoursInParttime - totalTracked) ?? 0;
                        }
                    }

                    newListOfSchedule.push({
                        user_id: user_id,
                        username: username,
                        modality: modality,
                        totalTracked: totalTracked ?? 0,
                        daily_hours: newDailyHours
                    });

                });
            });



      console.log(newListOfSchedule)
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```